# How to do claim based SSO for Android and IPhone applications using ADFS STS?

Tags: android, iphone, wcf, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

My client asks to authenticate Android and IPhone apps by Single Sign-On mechanism using ADFS. Once apps provides UserName and Password, ADFS will provide a token with claim to apps after authenticating them and this token is valid for some time only.

Before doing any start I have collected following question in my mind.

1. Does IPhone and Android apps support SAML 2.0 protocol ? If yes then I guess it's easy to implement.
2. If answer of #1 is no then I think we would require an intermediate service in WCF that translates/converts SAML 2.0 token into token supported by apps . Is it true?

Please provide me the right direction to implement this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have answer for your first question.

I understand that we can achieve this via **SAML** request. 
In this case would you be able to get the following during development:

- Service URL
- SAML Request Schema
- SAML Response Schema

You would also need the public key of signing certificate (and perhaps more).
Some federation setups allow you to exchange information with data contained in XML files, 
it depends on your implementation.
get **iDP federationMetadat.xml** file from client also get public key for signing certificate. 
Metadata and the signing certificate should be all that is needed, but please ask your client if you need anything else.